# How applicationcontext.xml is interpreted in struts and spring

Tags: spring, struts2, applicationcontext

i have one question on applicationcontext.xml...

when web.xml is interpreted by server(tomcat or whatever)..does it first see applicationcontext.xml or struts.xml

(Or) does it first see whether the struts.xml is there and then interpret applicationcontext.xml and then come back to struts.xml and include applicationcontext.xml environment into struts.xml and then interpret the struts.xml

i would like to know how the flow goes.

i am using struts2 and spring 3 framework...

Thank you all..

Comment: struts.xml is related to S2 and being handled by FilterDispatcher while application-context dependents how you specify to contextloader listern where to search for it.Both are different and work on there own way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>  
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.action</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Filters are initialised in order of occurrence. So most definitely struts.xml is read before applicationContext.xml however if reversed the opposite would be true. It is part of the servlet spec and explicitly stated here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

If however you used a servlet to access a resource, it would be initialised after the filters and the order can be controlled by the servlets load-on-startup element.

Comment: i think first applicationcontext.xml will be executed first. link... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000023 and so before request happens first listener will takes placed then filters comes...

Comment: I meant to say that each listener is instantiated in the order of appearance in the the web.xml, I would think that means that their configuration files would be parsed in that order too.